# Autenticação single sign on Django e Grafana

Tags: python-3.x, django

Olá pessoal estou utilizando os iframes do grafana em minha página HTML rodando em Django/python, porem toda vez que eu abro minha página para visualizar os graficos embedados eu preciso acessar o grafana e assim realizar o login para autenticar meu usuário, minha aplicação Django já tem uma página de login, gostaria de usar apenas um login em minha página e enviar uma requisição de proxy para o grafana, desta forma não preciso realizar dois logins toda vez que abrir minha aplicação.

Tentei utilizar desta forma:

**View**

```
class GraphanaProxyView(ProxyView):
    upstream = 'http://172.30.3.141:3000/'

    def get_proxy_request_headers(self, request):
        headers = super(GraphanaProxyView, self).get_proxy_request_headers(request)
        headers['X-WEBAUTH-USER'] = request.user.username
        return headers
```

**Urls**

```
url(r'^grafana/(?P<path>.*)$', views.GraphanaProxyView.as_view(), name='graphana-dashboards'),
```

**Config Grafana**

```
grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./grafana/datastore:/var/lib/grafana"

    environment:
      - GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true  
      - GF_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com:587
      - GF_SMTP_USER=user@domain.com.br
      - GF_SMTP_PASSWORD=password
      - GF_SMTP_FROM_NAME=Grafana Snipped
      - GF_SMTP_SKIP_VERIFY=true


      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_NAME=View
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=View
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false

      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_NAME = X-WEBAUTH-USER
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_PROPERTY=username       
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_AUTO_SIGN_UP=true 
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_LDAP_SYNC_TTL=60
      - GF_AUTH_PROXY_WHITELIST = 172.30.3.207
      - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN = 172.30.3.141
```

Estou recebendo esse erro quando acesso a URL:

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_path setting includes subpath
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: npm run dev, npm run watch, or npm run build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Desculpe não sei Portoguese, o Google Translated me ajudou)

Oi Gabriel
obrigado por entrar em contato comigo por e-mail também.

Seu relatório está quase completo, ótimo!

Dado o aviso

`` `Esta configuração também é importante se você tiver um proxy reverso na frente do Grafana que o expõe através de um subcaminho. Nesse caso, adicione o subcaminho ao final dessa configuração de URL . ``

em http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#root-url

uma falha pode ser a configuração do envvarro 'GF_SERVER_DOMAIN`que deve ser substituído pelo`GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL = http: //172.30.3.141: 3000 /` que contém a porta (e isso significaria um bug da documentação do Grafana ...)

Se não isso, apenas duas outras perguntas me vêm à mente para identificar o problema:

1. o seu request.user.username corresponde ao nome de usuário do Grafana?
 2. qual é o atributo "src" do seu iframe? Deve ser `https://172.30.3.207/grafana/(dashboard path)`

Ao lado destas questões básicas eu sugiro que você tente remover o envvar do `GF_AUTH_PROXY_WHITELIST` e tente autenticar via`curl` como:

`curl -H" X-WEBAUTH-USER: anthony "http: //172.30.3.141: 3000 / api / user`

como você pode encontrar em http://docs.grafana.org/auth/auth-proxy/#interacting-with-grafana-s-authproxy-via-curl

---

(Sorry I don't know Portoguese, Google Translated helped me)

Hi Gabriel,
thank you for contacting me by email also.

Your report is almost complete, great!

Given the warning

`This setting is also important if you have a reverse proxy in front of Grafana that exposes it through a subpath. In that case add the subpath to the end of this URL setting.`

at http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#root-url

a fault can be the setting of the `GF_SERVER_DOMAIN` envvar that should be replaced by the `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://172.30.3.141:3000/` that holds the port (and this would mean a bug of Grafana documentation...)

If not this, only two other questions come to my mind to identify the issue:

1. does your request.user.username match the Grafana username?
2. what is the "src" attribute of your iframe? It must be `https://172.30.3.207/grafana/(dashboard path)`

beside this basic questions I suggest you to try to remove the `GF_AUTH_PROXY_WHITELIST` envvar and to try to authenticate via `curl` like:

`curl -H "X-WEBAUTH-USER: anthony" http://172.30.3.141:3000/api/user`

as you can find at http://docs.grafana.org/auth/auth-proxy/#interacting-with-grafana-s-authproxy-via-curl

Comment: Fero, traduza sua resposta para português!

Comment: Luca, answering your question, the request.user.username I believe is not the same registered in grafana.

I have one a question, every time I register a new user in my application, the same user needs to be registered in grafana or this is generated automatically?

my iframe src is "<iframe src =" http://172.30.3.141:3000/d-solo/cFb9_r9mz/senseops-dashboard?refresh=5s&orgId=1&panelId=71&theme=light "width =" 100% "height = "200" frameborder = "0"> "

Comment: You are right. Try the curl and let me know